# how can i get chinese word using google api with JSON

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I Get Chinese Romanization from google API with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177615/how-can-i-get-chinese-romanization-from-google-api-with-json)

hay everyone.I'm translating English to Chinese using Google translate api with JSON.its work fine. but I also want to get one more word something like phonetic word.

ex. when I translate God to Chinese it gives chinese word as well as shan word beneath phonetic word. can anyone pls help me how can i get this word.

I'm using below link

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?q=god&v=2.0&langpair=en|zh

Comment: pls someone help me its urgent

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Pinyin? You may have to use a third-party database to get the Pinyin for a given character.
See the parser used here: http://zhongwenweb.com/parser.html