# how can I Get Chinese Romanization from google API with JSON

Tags: iphone, json, google-api

I want to translate English to Chinese and I got that working, but I also need Chinese Romanization. I.e., God should translate to to 神 as well as Shén; I couldn't get Shén. How can I do this?

Comment: Part of the problem here is that there are potentially multiple different pinyin romanizations for a single character, for instance 的, a very common character, can be rendered in pinyin as `de` or `dì`, depending on context.  Be aware of this as you make your application.

Comment: Also be aware that the Google Translation API is being deprecated, and will be turned off in December '11: so if you want your app to work past that you'd best find another source to use!

Answer (score 0):

I just have made minor changes to goslate (an unofficial API for google translator) to made it able to get the romanised translation, and named it goslater. I hope google give us this funcionality in the future, but for now, you can download goslater here:

https://sites.google.com/site/javialamo/python/mis-programas/modulos/goslater

https://github.com/javialamo/goslater

Hope it helps